Angular 17 Cold not resolve "rxjs/Observable" [plugin angular-rxjs-resolution]
I have an Angular project that works with MVC WEB API. This error is coming since the moment I added AuthService.
X [ERROR] Could not resolve "rxjs/Observable" [plugin angular-rxjs-resolution] 

    node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.js:7:27:
      7 │ import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
        ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "rxjs/Observable" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "rxjs/Observable" [plugin angular-rxjs-resolution] 

    node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js:21:27:
      21 │ var Observable_1 = require("rxjs/Observable");
         ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "rxjs/Observable" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.


X [ERROR] Could not resolve "rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise" [plugin angular-rxjs-resolution]

    node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js:22:8:
      22 │ require("rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise");
         ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.


X [ERROR] Could not resolve "rxjs/add/observable/defer" [plugin angular-rxjs-resolution]

    node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js:23:8:
      23 │ require("rxjs/add/observable/defer");
         ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "rxjs/add/observable/defer" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to 
handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.


X [ERROR] Could not resolve "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap" [plugin angular-rxjs-resolution]

    node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js:24:8:
      24 │ require("rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap");
         ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap" as external to exclude it 
from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in 
the bundle. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.


Application bundle generation failed. [0.242 seconds]

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "rxjs/Observable" [plugin angular-rxjs-resolution] 

    node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.js:7:27:
      7 │ import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
        ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "rxjs/Observable" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "rxjs/Observable" [plugin angular-rxjs-resolution] 

    node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js:21:27:
      21 │ var Observable_1 = require("rxjs/Observable");
         ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "rxjs/Observable" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.


X [ERROR] Could not resolve "rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise" [plugin angular-rxjs-resolution]

    node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js:22:8:
      22 │ require("rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise");
         ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.


X [ERROR] Could not resolve "rxjs/add/observable/defer" [plugin angular-rxjs-resolution]

    node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js:23:8:
      23 │ require("rxjs/add/observable/defer");
         ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "rxjs/add/observable/defer" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to 
handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap" [plugin angular-rxjs-resolution]

    node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js:24:8:
      24 │ require("rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap");
         ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap" as external to exclude it 
from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in 
the bundle. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

My authService:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginUser } from '../models/loginUser';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JwtHelper, tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertifyService } from './alertify.service';
import { RegisterUser } from '../models/registerUser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private alertifyService: AlertifyService
  ) {}
  path = 'http://localhost:4200/api/auth/';
  userToken: any;
  decodedToken: any;
  jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
  TOKEN_KEY = 'token';
  login(loginUser: LoginUser) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.httpClient
      .post(this.path + 'login', loginUser, { headers: headers })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.saveToken(data);
        this.userToken = data;
        this.decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(data.toString());
        this.alertifyService.success('Sisteme giriş yapıldı');
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/city');
      });
  }

  register(registerUser: RegisterUser) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.httpClient
      .post(this.path + 'register', registerUser, {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .subscribe((data) => {});
  }

  saveToken(token) {
    localStorage.setItem(this.TOKEN_KEY, token);
  }

  logOut() {
    localStorage.removeItem(this.TOKEN_KEY);
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired(this.TOKEN_KEY);
  }

  getCurrentUserId() {
    return this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(localStorage.getItem(this.TOKEN_KEY))
      .nameid;
  }
}


I just tried using it on my navbar.
my nav.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService:AuthService) { }

  loginUser:any={}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  login(){
    this.authService.login(this.loginUser);
  }

  logOut(){
    this.authService.logOut()
  }

  isAuthenticated(){
    return this.authService.loggedIn();
  }
  
  
}

I don't understand why I'm getting an Observable error even though I don't use Get. I'm new to Angular.
package.json :
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.5",
    "alertifyjs": "^1.14.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootswatch": "^5.3.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }


The error you're encountering with rxjs/Observable is likely due to a compatibility issue between the version of rxjs you're using and the angular2-jwt package. rxjs version 7 has introduced breaking changes, and angular2-jwt might not be updated to work with it.

@princ09 is probably correct. angular2-jwt version 0.2.3 uses RxJS 5.0.0, which has a different syntax. Run ng update angular2-jwt and you should be fine

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
